# Search match with for loop google app script

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am tying to execute a function to check if an email address matches a cell value in my spreadsheet and make an array of any matches but I can't seem to make it work.

I imagine it's an issue with the loop, although it's completing, I am not logging the array from logger.log.

Any help much appreciated!

```
`function searchEmail() {

var formOneSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses');
var lr = formOneSheet.getLastRow();
var formOneData = formOneSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var col_to_search = 1;
var formOneRow = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= lr; i++) {
  if(formOneData[0][col_to_search] === "abc@gmail.com"){

  return i;
  formOneRow.append(i);
  
  Logger.log(formOneRow);
  }}}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The code after `return i;` won't be executed since the function is
  terminated when [`return` is called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).
- Also in the for loop you don't use `i` to iterate over the array.
- Since the array index starts with 0, you don't want to include
  the length of the array as the upper limit in the for loop.
- You want to use [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- I assume you want to log the resulting list after the for loop.

Try this:

```
function searchEmail() {

var formOneSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses');
var lr = formOneSheet.getLastRow();
var formOneData = formOneSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var col_to_search = 1;
var formOneRow = [];

for (var i = 0; i < lr; i++) {
  if(formOneData[i][col_to_search] === "abc@gmail.com"){
   formOneRow.push(formOneData[i][col_to_search]);
 }
 } 
   Logger.log(formOneRow)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marios and the method makes sense but it just returns the row number where "abc@gmail.com" is located?

Comment: that's brilliant, working now! Thanks you for your help!